# What does $M_{x}$ denote in the given problem?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question on notation.

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an equicontinuous family of functions in $C(K)$, where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose that for each $x \in K$,
>
> $$\sup\{f(x):f \in \mathcal{F} \} = M_{x}$$
>
> is finite.

What are a few terms of $\{f(x):f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ supposed to look like? Do we take an arbitrary function and then find the supremum of $f(x)$ over all $x$ in $K$?

Comment: $x$ is fixed and $M_x$ is  the supremum of the numbers $f(x)$ as $f$ ranges over $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: so for $x$ fixed, then basically for functions $f, g, h, ...$ in $\mathcal{F}$, we take the supremum of $\{f(x),g(x),h(x),...\}$?

Comment: So, $f(x)\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson: yes